# Logs and domains

Tags: logarithms

Take $y=ln(x^2)$, it's domain is all real x except 0. Now if we use the power law we end up with $y=2ln(x)$. And this functions domain is positive x. So what causes this change in domain?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2023641/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cln(x%5E2)%20%3D%202%20%5Cln(x)%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Adomain)

Answer (score -1):

This is because according to power law,

y= log(x^2)=2(log|x|)

So, if f(x)= 2(log(x)),
log(x^2)=f|x|
Hence, both are different functions and hence can have different domains.